# What is causing this unexpected Javascript error?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

This code is meant to add the style 'display: none' to every element which does not have the class 'ShowThis', or a descendant with that class:

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
for(var i = x.length; i--;){
    x[i].style.display = 'none';
    if((' '+x[i].className+' ').indexOf(' ShowThis ') >= 0){
        var y = x[i];
        while(y){
            if(y.nodeType === 1){
                console.log(y.style.cssText);    // Outputs: "display: none;"
                console.log(y.style.display);    // Outputs: "none"
                y.style.display = 'block';
                console.log(y.style.display);    // Outputs: "block"
                console.log(y.style.cssText);    // Outputs: "display: block;"

                // ERROR here:
                    // Outputs the elements HTML (Chrome Console),
                    // But the style attribute isn't changed
                    // EX. <div style="display: none;">...</div>
                console.log(y);
            }
            y = y.parentNode;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/wEq8X/

It works fine if you comment out `if(y.nodeType === 1){` and the matching `}` (http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/wEq8X/1/), or if I change the if statement to `if(y.nodeType)` or `if(true)` which doesn't make any sense at all to me, since the program flow is entering that if statement (all the `console.log`'s are executed) anyways.

I've tried changing the if statement to `if(typeof y.style !== 'undefined')` and it behaves incorrectly as well. (Exactly the same problem)

I need to test nodeType or style to prevent the error when it tries to access the document's style property, but testing either of them gives me this weird behaviour.

I can repro this in Chrome, Firefox, and IE.

Comment: When removing removing `style.display = 'none'`, it should be set to `''` (empty string) as there are many elements whose default display property isn't *block* (the [display property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-display) has 16 different values in CSS 2.1). Setting to empty string allows the element to adopt its default or inherited style without you needing to do so explicity.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Your code depends on the order in which the page elements are returned. If a container element is seen *after* the inner elements, and the container does not have "ShowThis", then it won't work.

Comment: @RobG I didn't know the empty string would reset it to the default value. That's handy, thanks.

Comment: Ha ha - updated again. I need to get more sleep or something; I don't know how I missed that obvious detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code sets the **containing** block to "display: none".  After that, it doesn't matter that the inner `<div>` is "display: block".

Your diagnostic technique of dumping out the element is flawed. If you use something like the Chrome debugger or Firebug, you'll see that your "ShowThis" element does indeed have "display: block" in its "style" attribute. However, it doesn't show up because all its parent elements (including the `<body>` tag) are still "display: none".

*edit* I think the problem is probably something that stems from the order in which the page elements appear in the "getElementsByTagName()" result.  If you reach the parent elements *after* the child elements, then they'll be set to "display: none" *after* they've been set to "display: block".

*edit again* — confirmed. The elements are returned from "getElementsByTagName()" appear in **reverse order** that they appear in the HTML.  Thus, the last element your code sees in the **outer** loop is the container `<div>` for the "ShowThis" `<div>`.

*edit yet again* oh dang I see - you're going backwards!!  Durr.  If you go forward through the node list, it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote.  Any explanation?  My statements are accurate.

Comment: It has while loop to iterate upwards and set all the ancestors to have 'display: block;'. That's not the problem.

Comment: I'm afraid you're mistaken, @PaulPRO. It clearly does not work.

Comment: It's true that the parent elements have 'display: none', but that's the bug. This code changes it, and `console.log(y.style.display);` outputs 'block' for every ancestor (Check the Chrome debugger), then when I output the actual element it hasn't changed.

Comment: When it's done, however, the parent nodes don't have the right style. I think I know why that is too.

Comment: I see your edit, but the weird part is that it works fine if I  comment out the if statement: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/wEq8X/1/ It wouldn't work if the elements were being hidden after they are shown. And since getElementsbyTagName returns elements in the order they're found in a depth first search of the DOM tree that shouldn't be an error anyways.

Comment: Ah! Thanks so much. The problem was just that I was iterating backwards through the result set of getElementsByTagName. Here's the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/wEq8X/7/

Comment: If you edit your answer to show the fix by iterating in the correct direction I will accept your answer, since you're the one who helped me solve it ):

Answer (score 1):

You issue is that your outer loop that hides everything will hide the 'showthis' node's parents after you set then to display='block'. If you split the hiding and showing into two steps, it works fine.

```
var y, x = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
for(var i = 0, len = x.length; i < len; i++){
    x[i].style.display = 'none';
}
x = document.getElementsByClassName('ShowThis');
for(var i = 0, len = x.length; i < len; i++) {
    y = x[i];
    while(y){
        if(y.nodeType === 1){
            y.style.display = 'block';
        }
        y = y.parentNode;
    }
}
```

Also, just for the record, this type of thing is where jQuery is awesome.

```
jQuery('*').hide();
jQuery('.ShowThis').show().parents().show();
```

Comment: I know, I wanted to give pass this script out to my friends though as something which removes the junk around our University timetables to make it nicer for printing, haha. The Universities website doesn't use jQuery.

Comment: Thank you btw, this solution also works, but I just had to iterate forwards to fix it. I was iterate backwards through the result set of getElementsByTagName.

Comment: Nice. You should consider making it a GreaseMonkey script. If iterating the other way works, great. I can't promise that will work in all browsers though. It all depends on the order of things from getElementsByTagName. Not sure if the order is part of the Specs.